# Taking screenshot of windows phone  7.5 and sending over through TCP

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

i am stuck on how to take a screenshot of my windows phone 7.5 and sending it over TCP. i have no experience in doing socket program and I/O and am doing what i can through tutorials over the internet. This is what i have done.

From the codes below i am stuck in how i can send the writeableBitMap over TCP encoded as a Jpeg periodically running in the WP7.5 background, whereby a program on a desktop will receive it as a jpeg image so it can be displayed creating a windows phone to desktop streaming effect.

my mainPage of my windows phone 7.5 application using a library i have created from a tutorial for taking care of the sockets connection.

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.IO;

namespace helloworld
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor
        SocketLibrary.socketLib sl = new SocketLibrary.socketLib();
        private string hostIP = "127.0.0.1";
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            bool retVal;

            retVal = sl.EstablishTCPConnection(hostIP);

            WriteableBitmap bmpCurrentScreenImage = new WriteableBitmap((int)this.ActualWidth, (int)this.ActualHeight);

            var ms = new MemoryStream();
            // Send the picture.
            bmpCurrentScreenImage.SaveJpeg(ms, bmpCurrentScreenImage.PixelWidth, bmpCurrentScreenImage.PixelHeight, 0, 90);
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            retVal = sl.Send(ms);

            sl.CloseSocket();
        }


    }
}
```

the socket library

```
   namespace SocketLibrary
{
    public class socketLib
    {
        Socket s = null;
        static ManualResetEvent done = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        private Int16 portNo = 3334;

        public socketLib()
        {


        }
        public bool EstablishTCPConnection(string host)
        {
            s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream,
            ProtocolType.Tcp);
            SocketAsyncEventArgs socketEventArg = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
            socketEventArg.RemoteEndPoint = new DnsEndPoint(host, portNo);
            socketEventArg.Completed += new
            EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(delegate(object o, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
            {
                done.Set();
            });
            done.Reset();
            s.ConnectAsync(socketEventArg);
            return done.WaitOne(10000);
        }

        public bool Send(MemoryStream data)
        {
            byte[] msData = data.ToArray();
            if (s != null)
            {
                SocketAsyncEventArgs socketEventArg = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
                socketEventArg.RemoteEndPoint = s.RemoteEndPoint;
                socketEventArg.UserToken = null;

                socketEventArg.Completed += new
                EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(delegate(object o, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
                {
                    done.Set();
                });

                socketEventArg.SetBuffer(msData, 0, msData.Length);
                done.Reset();
                s.SendAsync(socketEventArg);
                return done.WaitOne(10000);
            }
            return false;
        }

        public void CloseSocket()
        {
            if (s != null)
            {
                s.Close();
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

check this

http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2011/05/Windows-Phone-Screen-Shots.html

http://blog.galasoft.ch/archive/2010/12/28/taking-a-screenshot-from-within-a-silverlight-wp7-application.aspx